# How to interpret higher RMSE and $R^2$?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, model-evaluations

I ran an evaluation on two different regression model variations using the same dataset and I am a bit unsure how to tell which model is better.

The blue model has a worse RMSE of 150 and a better $R^2$ score of .107.

I was hoping to see if anyone had any thoughts on how to interpret this in relation to determining which model is more accurate.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [What you’ve described is impossible in math](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/592424/247274), so there is something about the implementation that is not reporting what you think it is reporting. How are those RMSE and $R^2$ values calculated in the software you’re using?

Comment: Both the r2 are very poor, so saying 0.107 is better than 0.044 is not of much use. Also, the sample count seems different for both.